# How to return result set from PostgreSQL stored procedure?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

PostgreSQL supports stored procedure (**not function**) since version 11. I created a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_user_list ()
  LANGUAGE SQL
  SECURITY DEFINER
  AS $$
  SELECT "id",
         "username",
         "display_name"
  FROM "user"
  ORDER BY "created_at" ASC;
$$;
```

But when I am trying to execute this stored procedure, it does not return any data:

```
postgres=# CALL get_user_list();
CALL
postgres=# SELECT * FROM get_user_list();
ERROR:  get_user_list() is a procedure
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM get_user_list();
                      ^
HINT:  To call a procedure, use CALL.
```

So the question is, how can a stored procedure returns its result set in PostgreSQL 11+?

Comment: You need to define what the stored procedure returns. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41035386/postgresql-stored-procedure-return-select-result-set) for example.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: That misunderstanding is probably due to the widespread misnomer "stored procedure". *SQL procedures* are not *functions*. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/194811/3684

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter `SQL procedures are not functions` - I wouldn't name it misnomer. Both Oracle and SQL Server support returning resultset from stored procedure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following the **[docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING-PROCEDURE)** on Postgres 11 (bold emphasis mine):

> A procedure **does not have a return value**. A procedure can therefore end without a RETURN statement. If a RETURN statement is desired to exit the code early, then NULL must be returned. Returning any other value will result in an error.

You could mark your parameters as output though, so that they would behave like variables.

On a side note there's normally a distinction within other DBMS that functions can only call SELECT statements and should not modify data while procedures should be handling the data manipulation and data definition languages (DML, DDL). This concludes (in my opinion) that creating a procedure to simply perform a stable *(*)* select statement is not the desired technique.

(*) Read more on function volatility [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/static/xfunc-volatility.html).

Answer (score 1):

In case if you have one select in procedure to get result set you can create view like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW get_user_list as 
  SELECT "id",
         "username",
         "display_name"
  FROM "user"
  ORDER BY "created_at" ASC;
```

and then `select * from get_user_list` to get result set.