# How to return a resultset from PostgreSQL stored procedure?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-11

Could anyone able to help me how to return a resultset from postgres sql stored procedure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgresql stored procedure return select result set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41035386/postgresql-stored-procedure-return-select-result-set)

Comment: Use a function that is much, much easier

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
CALL procedure_name(arg1, arg2);
```

will return a result set if the procedure has `INOUT` parameters.